# longtable + itemize + resize

Tags: lists, longtable, itemize

i'm trying to rezise a longtable that contains itemize...can you help me?
if i put `\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{` I have error.
My table start as:

```
\begin{centre}\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|p{9cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\caption[Features]{Features} \label{features} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Study} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Feature}  &\textbf{Metrics} &\textbf{Classifier}\\ 
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\\
hetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline 
\textbfStudy} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Feature}  &\textbf{Metrics} &\textbf{Classifier}\\ 
 \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot


...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: If the solutions below do not solve your issue, please keep in mind that it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you. Basically, show the problem instead of describing it.

Comment: One possible idea is to use features of [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) but don't know if it will solve your issue without a test case.

Answer (score 4):

`\resizebox` as its name implies makes a *box* so the result will never break, which defeats the point of longtable, If you reduce the numbers in

```
{|l|l|p{9cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
```

then the table will fit on the width and will not need scaling. Or if you *want* smaller text don't use scaling, just put `\small` before the table.

Comment: the problem is the height not the width, beacusa with itemize the table is not split on pages...

Comment: I don't understand. (maybe you need to supply a full example). But the fact remains, that if you need to put it in a box, use a normal tabular, not longtable.

Comment: eheh table is long about 8 pages...

Comment: This is why we ask people to put a MWE in the question (you can edit your question and add one) it is then much easier to see the constraints. Clearly the table is not 8 pages long in a `\resizebox` it will just be in one over-long table. The solution is likely to be do not use itemize but to put each item in a row of the table, so it can break, or to not use a table at all, and just use an itemize, which can also break. Impossible to say without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 3):

a `longtable` cannot be resized with `\resizebox` when it has a page break. Use something like

```
\small
... your longtable ...

\normalsize
```

or use the package `ltxtable` which allows a longtable with X columns as possible for `tabularx`. Run "`texdoc ltxtable`" for the syntax.

Comment: the problem is the height not the width, beacusa with itemize the table is not split on pages...

Comment: then the `itemize` is longer than a page and a `longtable` can have only a pagebreak _between_ two tabular lines! Close the `itemize` environment and start a new one in a new tabular line, where a page break may make sense.

Comment: I've already tried but table then consider 2 itemize the same one...

Comment: @Cristina: I second Herbert's suggestion on closing `itemize` when possible. Speaking of items, what if you use `compactitem` from the `paralist` package instead of `itemize`? It's the `itemize` environment with all the vertical skips set to zero, it might save some space.